# G++ compiler not appearing in path

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, installation, path, mingw-w64

I am installing the 64-bit GCC compiler to use in visual studio code. I added the MinGW binary directory to environmental variables but when running g++ or gdb in command prompt it is not recognized as a command. I am certain the file path is correct because I can run the applications in the installation folder. I have tried restarting my computer and command prompt but the problem persists.

This is what I see so far: [desktop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38Cdx.png)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

These are the guides I am following:

1. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw
2. https://www.msys2.org/

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add it to your path in the environment variables, in the start search bar search environment variables and it should bring up a shortcut to where you can change and add to the environment variables, just need to add it to the path

Answer (score 0):

you should add the bin path to `Path` environment variable， but not create
a `Mingw` environment variable.